# C++ async makes program unresponsive

Tags: c++, asynchronous, gstreamer

I'm currently trying to create a C++ wrapper for my program to use GStreamer.

So I have created a Class "Audio" with a method "play" that starts a stream. Because of the call to `g_main_loop_run` inside it, it won't return until the main loop quits.
I dont want that behaviour and thus I'm trying to make an `async` call to another method within the `play` method, which would then start the main loop and allow the `play` method to return.

It currently looks like this:

```
    void play(const char* uri) {
        stop();

        if (uri) {
            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(pipeline), "uri", uri, NULL);
        } else {
            cout << "Please specify an URI you wish to play" << endl;
            return;
        }
        gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT(pipeline), GST_STATE_PLAYING);

        auto handle = async( launch::async, &Audio::playAsync, this, uri);
    }

    void playAsync(const char* uri) {
            cout << "playing async" << endl;
        g_main_loop_run(this->getLoop());
    }
```

But the result is that the program is getting unresponsive... the `playAsync` method is called (its printing the cout), and playback starts and continues to play, but the GUI becomes totally unresponsive and can only be quit by killing the program.

Do you have any help for me?

regards, tagelicht

Comment: When does `g_main_loop_run` return? Also `play` should probably push the `uri` to another system (or subsystem) that handles `std::async` and its returned `std::future` internally; or uses `std::thread`

Comment: Yes, the problem was I did not understand that the future of async() waits for the function to return, and `g_main_loop_run` usually returns after a few minutes or so (when the stream is finished/stopped) :( I now use what @KABoissonneault suggested: `thread t(&Audio::playAsync, this, uri); t.detach();` And it works just fine :) But I dont understand what you mean with the `uri` variable, this way it gets passed to `playAsync` without problems. EDIT: Oh :D I just realized you posted this half an hour ago, sorry^^

Answer (score 2):

Async returns future and future must be finished (it waits for the result) when it goes out of scope.
It's exactly the same as using just `async(...);` as handle goes out of scope just after assigment.

Comment: OK thanks for your reply but if future must be finished, how do I tell it to just call the function asynchronously and not wait for the result?

Comment: @tagelicht Either move the `std::future` out of the function and have it wait somewhere else, or use `std::thread` and `std::thread::detach`